# Creating call objects to compare to formula elements

Tags: r

I would like to create an object from a string to compare with an element of a formula.

For example, in the following:

```
# note that f does not exist
myForm <- y ~ f(x)
theF <- myForm[[3]]
fString <- "f(x)"
```

How can I compare `fString` to `theF`?

If I know the string is "f(x)" I can manually enter the following

```
cheating <- as.call(quote(f(x)))
identical(theF, cheating)
```

which works (it gives TRUE) but I want to be able to take the string "f(x)" as an argument (e.g. maybe it's "g(x)".

The real point of this question is for me to understand better how to work with call objects and `quote` function.

Comment: Is this what you want: `fString == deparse(theF)` ?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck actually I want the opposite. I want something such that `identical(theF, something)` is `TRUE`, where I do not change `theF`.

Comment: Try: `identical(theF, parse(text = fString)[[1]])` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes that's perfect. Can you add that as an answer? Can you also, if possible, add the intuition that led you to that answer? Did you do a lot of experiments or did you somehow know that would work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse(text = s)` converts text, `s`, to an expression and `e[[1]]` extracts the call object from a length 1 expression `e`.  `theF` is a call object so putting these together we have:

```
 identical(theF, parse(text = fString)[[1]])
 ## TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

note that formula's are really nothing on their own in R.
the only thing they do is convert it into a string like object...
"y~f(x)"

it's then on to the functions that accept formulas to interpret it...
check coplot for an example implementation